# How to start Pacific Fighters

Tags: il2-sturmovik-1946, technical-issues

I bought and installed the IL-2 Sturmovik 1946. The box says it includes Forgotten Battles, Ace Expansion Pack, and Pacific Fighters.

But I don't see any Pacific Fighters shortcut in my Start Menu. How do I start Pacific Fighters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer. As I understand, they merged all missions, aircraft, etc. in one single installation.
[image]

http://il2-sturmovik.de.ubi.com/en/home.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for executables in the program install folder? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7, click the Windows button on the lower left hand side of the screen, then search for either "IL-2" or "Sturmovik" in the search field and that should find it.